# Editing variable labels for dotplot of (g)lmer object with R/Lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I'm using the `glmer()` function from the `lme4` package to estimate a complex mixed effects models with multiple random effects. After the model is estimated, I'm using the `dotplot()` function from the `lattice` package to create a dotplot of the random effects, which include varying slopes. My inquiry concerns how to edit the variable labels in the dotplot

A simple reproducible example of my problem goes as follows.

```
library(lattice)
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
sleepstudy$x <- rnorm(180)
M1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + x + (Days + x | Subject), sleepstudy)

dotplot(ranef(M1, condVar=TRUE), ylab="Levels", main=FALSE,
    scales = list(x =list(relation = 'free')))[["Subject"]]
```

This produces the following dotplot, which approximates what I want.

[image]

What I would like to do is edit the variable labels. Namely, I'd like to remove the parentheses from "(Intercept)", and change the labels for both varying slopes to be something other than the variable names called into `glmer()`. Is that possible? I'm sure it is and that it's likely a "strip" option, though I'm not sure what exactly it would be.

I'd be open to a `ggplot2` solution as well. Either/or is fine as long as it gets to what I want. In fact, a `ggplot2` solution might be better if it allows me to adjust the bounds on the conditional variance to something like 1.645*se. I don't think `lattice` will give me that option.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do this assuming no native renaming functionality is to add an intermediate variable that you assign `ranef(M1,condVar=TRUE)` to, which I call `model`. Then you can use `colnames()` to rename the labels.

## Solution:

```
library(lattice)
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
sleepstudy$x <- rnorm(180)
M1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + x + (Days + x | Subject), sleepstudy)

model <- ranef(M1,condVar=TRUE)
colnames(model[[1]]) <- c("Intercept","Days","x") # Add your labelshere

dotplot(model, ylab="Levels", main=FALSE,
        scales = list(x =list(relation = 'free')))[["Subject"]]
```

Alternatively, you could coerce this to a `data.frame()` or `data.table()` and use this in `ggplot2` as you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much. Next step might be to see about a `ggplot2` solution since that may give me some flexibility about reporting the bounds of the variation for each levels of the random effect.